# Are humans above angels?

Tags: life-of-jesus, nature-of-god, angels, nature-of-man

In this verse Hebrews 2:7 it says that we are a little lower than the angels.

My question is, if Jesus (God) took the human nature and this way he shared his divinity with the human nature. Doesn't this make human nature above all the angelic natures? Even equal to God nature? Jesus give us a hint in Psalm 82:6. And here Peter says how he shares his divinity with us. 

 2 Peter 1:3-11

Can we imagine how the angels must have felt when Jesus decided to take the human flesh? Their God was leaving them and bringing His glory to us and not to angels...

My second question is can the fallen angels be saved if Jesus would become an angel and dies for them?

Because it's not anywhere as a teaching I'm not requiring a specific denomination point of view. If this question can only be answered hypothetically, I'm here to argue that there are scriptures that tells us something so we can avoid hypothetical answers.

Comment: I just put them in the question

Comment: What do you mean by "above"? Closer to God? More intelligent? Physically higher? This question is unanswerable without some definitions.

Comment: @Flimzy- having as much of Gods attributes as possible. Closers to God in every way...

Comment: "we can avoid hypothetical answers." I just don't think this question can do that.

Answer (score 2):

**Question 1: Are humans somehow above Angels?**

Psalm 8 is very clear - Man is lower than Angel.

> 4 what is mankind that you are mindful of them,
>       human beings that you care for them?
>   5 You have made them a little lower than the angels
>       and crowned them with glory and honor.

Philippians 2 is clear that this debasement was part of God's plan:

> In your relationships with one another, have the same mindset as Christ Jesus:
>
> 6 Who, being in very nature God,
>       did not consider equality with God something to be used to his own advantage;
>   7 rather, he made himself nothing
>       by taking the very nature of a servant,
>       being made in human likeness.
>   8 And being found in appearance as a man,
>       he humbled himself
>       by becoming obedient to death—
>           even death on a cross!
>   **Therefore God exalted him to the highest place**
>       and gave him the name that is above every name,
>   10 that at the name of Jesus every knee should bow,
>       in heaven and on earth and under the earth,
>   11 and every tongue acknowledge that Jesus Christ is Lord,
>       to the glory of God the Father

The thing you are adding - that somehow Jesus' incarnation is applicable to all humanity is the part that makes no sense.  The burden would be on you to prove that.

Finally, Jesus' did not "mix" the natures - Traditionally the [hypostatic union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypostatic_union) says he was fully God and fully man - but there is never a suggestion that the two natures were combined into one essence.

**Question 2: Ministering to Fallen Angels**

As to Jesus becoming an Angel - he didn't need to.  The closest one could come to understanding this would be in 1 Peter 3:19 20:

> For Christ also suffered once for sins, the righteous for the unrighteous, to bring you to God. He was put to death in the body but made alive in the Spirit. 19 After being made alive,[d] he went and made proclamation to the imprisoned spirits— 20 to those who were disobedient long ago when God waited patiently in the days of Noah while the ark was being built.

Some view this as Christ preaching to the Angels - but there is never a suggestion that Angels need atonement. This isn't to say they are perfect, nor that they aren't fallen, but we just have no biblical information about this.

Comment: Isn't humanity called the "crown of creation," presumably placing man "above" angels?

Comment: Where do you get than from?

Comment: @AffableGeek, 'Some view this as Christ preaching to the Angels' - no he was talking about dead people who died before Jesus died for us.

Comment: Some people. Not you.

Comment: @AffableGeek: I can't remember, and google isn't helping, so I may be mis-remembering.

Comment: @Grasper Is this a [Truth Question](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1696/are-truth-questions-inherently-off-topic-or-just-a-bad-question-smell) or are you looking for established theology?

Comment: @AffableGeek: [The Voice](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+1%3A29-31&version=VOICE) refers to humans as the crown of God's creation, but I'm not sure how much theological water that holds :)

Comment: It's also aserted by various Bible study materials such as [this one](http://www.wordexplain.com/manimage.html), but that doesn't seem to be strictly Biblical.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16374/discussion-between-affable-geek-and-flimzy).

Answer (score 0):

You err in misreading the Scriptures.

Let us begin with your second question first.

Jesus could not become an Angel in the first place since both are of the Spiritual realm, and Angels are the servants of God of which Jesus Christ is a part. There is another cogent reason why the fallen angels cannot be saved that reason is that the fallen Angels have already made the choice which we as humans face which is whether or not to rebel against God's authority. We as humans have the choice as long as we live to accept God, but the Angels have all already made that choice.

Once our physical life is over and we enter the Spiritual realm our decision is irreversible and we will either be judged at the Beamer judgment or the Great white throne judgment.

Now for the first part of your question:

Jesus did not share his divinity with us! What Jesus did was to become an acceptable sacrifice for our sins, and his blood put on the Altar of God made us acceptable to enter the Kingdom of Heaven.

As far as man being a little lower than the Angels, In the Spiritual World that is true since the Angels currently in Heaven are already in the process of serving God, which we cannot do until we transition to the Spiritual realm.

to better understand this you might start by reading the books of the Pentateuch, and then rereading the Gospels. It is very difficult to understand the New Testament without a clear understanding of the Old Testament.

Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry, but you are wrong. Jesus shared his divinity with us! 2 Peter 1:3-11

Comment: You better read that passage again it does not say God shared his divinity with us, only that through his grace has he given us all of those things. There is only one divine, and that is God himself in the form of the Trinity. that is why Satan was kicked out of Heaven, because he claimed to be divine

Comment: @Grasper my last comment was for you.

Comment: but we can be divine when we take part on his divinity. That's how I understand that verse.

Comment: Taking part on his divinity means, follow what Jesus was teaching and applying faith in Him, makes us holy/divine.

Comment: @Grasper That would be an interpretation that some have come to, but it would be out of step with the majority of Christendom.  What faith perspective are you representing with that statement? My guesses are Word of Faith or LDS - but there are others.

Comment: so then I think it's time to create new denomination, right? How can we prevent it from another split?

Comment: @ Grasper have you reread the Scriptures you quoted as backup for your assertion, or are you arguing from a Denominational concept? My answers and quotes are strictly Scriptural, and I do not argue from a Denominational standpoint or on this site. I have given you the Scriptures how you interpret them is up to you, but you might like to get yourself a Bible study program and take about a decade studying it yourself as I have done. You will learn quickly that Scripture explains itself, but you must search out the Scriptures which go together. The Bible is God's word. The Holy Spirit teaches.

Comment: @ Grasper There are no Denominations in the Kingdom of God. Splits and arguments are not of God, it does not please God that we demean others for any reason, and especially in that way. Nowhere in any Bible will you find that God designates a Denomination. We are all God's children if we are truly saved.